# Power View Error - an item with the same key has already been added

Tags: powerpivot, powerview

I need a solution in resolving an `error` which pops out in `Microsoft Power View`. After creating  the model using `Excel Power Pivot` without any `linkage errors`, I tried to create `Power views` from the `model`. But it pops out the there as:

> an item with the same key has already been added

It will be of great help if some one shares the solution as I am not able to drill and resolve further.

Comment: Can you create an Excel Pivot Table from the model?

Comment: @Rory: Yes.I m able to do that

Comment: Is this happening with one particular data model or with all models that you create?

Comment: @Rory: only with one particular data model. I already created power views with other data model in similar fashion.

Comment: If this is happening with a standalone rdlx file on sharepoint you could drill down by viewing the dax code of the powerview and executing that against the workbook with DAX Studio. If this is powerview within Excel I would recommend logging the bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/. Log it under SQL Server.